# Can someone help revise the style file to make captions of figures as Figure 1.1, 1.2...2.1,2.2 ...3.1,3.2?

Tags: numbering, captions

Now it seems that the captions are numbered from 1,2,3,......
I want it numbered as Figure 2.1, Figure 2.2,... Figure 3.1, ...

The style file is as follows:

```
\@ifundefined{DeclareOption}{}{% LaTeX2e option
\ProvidesPackage{cuthesis}[2003/04/04 \space  v 1.2]

\DeclareOption{manuscript}{\def\@wantmanuscript{true}}
\DeclareOption{standard}{}

\DeclareOption{phd}{\def\@phddissertation{true}}
\DeclareOption{masters}{}

\DeclareOption{nocopy}{\def\@nolibraryrights{true}}
\DeclareOption{copy}{}

\DeclareOption{noleadpages}{\def\@noleadpages{true}}
\DeclareOption{leadpages}{}

\DeclareOption{norefbib}{\def\@norefbib{true}}
\DeclareOption{refbib}{}

\DeclareOption{noextrapages}{\def\@noleadpages{true}\def\@norefbib{true}}
\DeclareOption{extrapages}{}

\DeclareOption{nonsequential}{\def\@wantnonsequential{true}}
\DeclareOption{sequential}{\def\@wantsequential{true}}

\DeclareOption{4committee}{\def\@fourcommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{5committee}{\def\@fivecommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{3committee}{\def\@threecommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{2committee}{\def\@twocommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{1committee}{}

\ProcessOptions
}

\@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
  % standard
  \@ifundefined{@wantnonsequential}{}{\def\@nonsequential{true}}
}{
  % manuscript
  \@ifundefined{@wantsequential}{\def\@nonsequential{true}}{}
}

\def\bibliocite#1{%
  \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{#1}}\fi}

\@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{

\@ifundefined{@extra@b@citeb}{
% this is for use without the cite package
\def\@citex[#1]#2{%
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\hbox{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
}
{
% this is for use with the cite package
\def\@nocite#1{\xdef\@no@sparg{\@ignsp#1 \! }% remove *ALL* spaces
 \if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout {\string\citation {\@no@sparg}}\fi
 \if@filesw \immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@no@sparg}}\fi}
}

}
{

% this section is basically chapterbib

\newenvironment{cbunit}%
{\global\advance\c@inputfile\@ne \xdef\the@ipfilectr{@-\the\c@inputfile}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@extra@binfo{\@exele@b@citeb}}}%
{\gdef\the@ipfilectr{}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@extra@binfo{\@exele@b@citeb}}%
  }

\let\cb@include\include
\def\include#1{\clearpage \cbunit \xdef\@currentipfile{#1}%
  \cb@include{#1}%
\refsforcb%
\global\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname\endcbunit}

\newcommand\cbinput[1]{\cbunit \xdef\@currentipfile{#1}%
  \input{#1}\global\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname\endcbunit}

\@ifundefined{@extra@binfo}{%
  \def\bibcite#1#2{\global\@namedef{b@#1\@extra@binfo}{#2}}%
}{}

\@ifundefined{@exele@b@citeb}{%
 \def\@citex[#1]#2{%
   \let\@citea\@empty%
   \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do%
     {\@citea\let\@citea\citepunct%
      \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@iden\@citeb}%
      \ifnum0=\value{mychapcitecount}%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibstyle{cubiblio}}\fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{\@reffile}}\fi%
      \setcounter{mychapcitecount}{1}%
      \fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi%
      \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb \@exele@b@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bf ?}%
         \@warning{Citation `\@citeb' in file `\@currentipfile'
             on page \thepage \space undefined}\G@refundefinedtrue}%
      {\hbox{\citeform{\csname b@\@citeb \@exele@b@citeb\endcsname}}}}}{#1}}
}{}% 2nd arg of \@ifundefined{@exele@b@citeb}

\def\@iden#1{#1}

\@ifundefined{citeform}{\let\citeform=\relax}{}
\@ifundefined{citepunct}{\def\citepunct{,\penalty\@m\ }}{}

\xdef\@savedjobname{\jobname}% save root file name as a macro
\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname
\gdef\the@ipfilectr{}
\def\@exele@b@citeb{\the@ipfilectr}
\newcount\c@inputfile \global\c@inputfile=0

\gdef\@extra@binfo{}  % in case .aux files are left from old run.

\@ifundefined{reset@font}{\let\reset@font\relax}{}
\@ifundefined{G@refundefinedtrue}{\let\G@refundefinedtrue\relax}{}

\let\cb@bibliographystyle\bibliographystyle
\def\cb@roottest{2\ifx\the@ipfilectr\@empty 1\else2\fi}

\def\bibliographystyle#1{\if\cb@roottest\cb@bibliographystyle{#1}\fi}

\def\bibliography#1{\if\cb@roottest%
   \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#1}}\fi%
   \fi \@input{\@currentipfile.bbl}}

\@ifundefined{PackageWarning}{\def\cb@warning{\@warning}}%
 {\def\cb@warning{\PackageWarning{chapterbib}}}

\let\@test@defiii\@testdef

\def\@testdef#1#2#3{%
  \if#1b\relax\@test@defiii b{#2\@extra@binfo}{#3}%
  \else \@test@defiii #1{#2}{#3}\fi%
}

\@ifundefined{bibname}{\def\bibname{Bibliography}}{}

% end of chapterbib section
}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\newcounter{myfigcount}
\newcounter{mytablecount}
\newcounter{myeqncount}
\newcounter{mychapcitecount}
\newcounter{mychaptercount}
\newcounter{myappendixcount}

\def\myusefigurespage{%
  \gdef\@myusefigurespage{true}
}

\def\myusetablespage{%
  \gdef\@myusetablespage{true}
}


\makeatletter

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.2in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1in}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.25in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.6in}
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}

\brokenpenalty=10000

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} % 1.3 spacing for tables and arrays

\def\myps@plain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
  \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
  \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
}

\def\ele@chapapp{}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}


\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\def\cl@chapter{%
  \setcounter{mychapcitecount}{0}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@elt{section}\@elt{footnote}%
  }{%
    \@elt{equation}\@elt{figure}\@elt{footnote}\@elt{section}\@elt{table}%
  }}
\def\thefigure{%
  \addtocounter{myfigcount}{\value{figure}}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@figure%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\@arabic\c@figure%
  }}
\def\thetable{%
  \addtocounter{mytablecount}{\value{table}}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@table%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\@arabic\c@table%
  }}
\def\theequation{%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@equation%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\arabic{equation}%
  }}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{\def\baselinestretch{1}\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
   \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}\@makefntext
    {\rule{\z@}{\footnotesep}\ignorespaces
      #1\strut}}}

\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{List of References
\@mkboth{}{}}\list
 {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin
\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.70\baselineskip}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

\def\thesisbib{\chapter*{Bibliography
\@mkboth{}{}}\trivlist
 \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.70\baselineskip}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthesisbib=\endtrivlist

\def\dept#1{\gdef\@dept{#1}}
\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\def\firstcommittee#1{\gdef\@firstcommittee{#1}}
\def\secondcommittee#1{\gdef\@secondcommittee{#1}}
\def\thirdcommittee#1{\gdef\@thirdcommittee{#1}}
\def\fourthcommittee#1{\gdef\@fourthcommittee{#1}}
\def\departmentchair#1{\gdef\@departmentchair{#1}}
\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}} % \author, \title in report
\def\@title{}\def\@author{}\def\@dept{Mechanical and Aerospace Engineering}
\def\@supervisor{} \def\@firstcommittee{} \def\@secondcommittee{}
\def\@thirdcommittee{} \def\@fourthcommittee{} \def\@departmentchair{}
\def\@copyrightyear{\number\the\year}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\submitdate{#1}}

\def\@reffile{references}

\def\reffile#1{%
  \def\@reffile{#1}
}

\def\abstract#1{%
  \def\@abstract{#1}
}

\def\acknowledgements#1{%
  \def\@acknowledgements{#1}
}

\def\contributions#1{%
  \def\@contributions{#1}
}

\def\dedication#1{%
  \def\@dedication{#1}
}

\def\acronyms#1{%
  \def\@acronyms{#1}
}

\def\symbols#1{%
  \def\@symbols{#1}
}


\def\@bibliofileext{bib}
\def\@bibliofile{\jobname\@bibliofileext}

\def\@awork{%
\@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
  thesis
}{
  dissertation
}}

% Print title page
\def\titlep{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\bf\@title}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        by\\
        \mbox{}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        {\textbf{\@author}}\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{center}
        A \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
      Thesis
    }{
       Dissertation
    } submitted to \\
    the Faculty of Graduate Studies and Research\\
    in partial fulfilment of\\
    the requirements for the degree of\\

    \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
    % CHAGE BELOW MASTER OF ARTS TO MASTER OF SCIENCE OR DOCTOR OF PHIL...

 \textbf{\\Master of Applied Science in Electrical and Computer Engineering}\\
}{
 \textbf{Doctor of Philosophy}\\
}
%\mbox{in}
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}
   % \begin{center}
      % Electrical and Computer Engineering
    %\end{center}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{center}
        \@dept\\
        xxxx University\\
        xxxx\\
        \submitdate\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{center}
        Copyright \copyright\\
        \@copyrightyear\ - \@author
    \end{center}\clearpage}


\long\def\signature#1{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{4in}
    \vspace{.4in}
    \hbox{\hfil\shortstack{\vrule width 3in height 0.4pt \\#1}}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\comprof{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}
  \begin{flushright}
    \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
      Thesis
    }{
       Dissertation
    }
    Committee\\
    Supervisor
  \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}

% Print signature approval page
\def\signaturepage{%
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\begin{center}
    The undersigned recommend to\\
    the Faculty of Graduate Studies and Research\\
    acceptance of the \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
      Thesis
    }{
       Dissertation
    }\\
\end{center}
\mbox{}
\begin{center}
    {\large\bf\@title}
\end{center}
\mbox{}
\begin{center}
    Submitted by \textbf{\@author}\\
    in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of\\
        \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
 \textbf{\bf{Master of Science}}\\
}{
 \textbf{\bf{Doctor of Philosophy}}\\
}
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
      & \signature{\@supervisor}\\
    \@ifundefined{@twocommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@threecommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@fourcommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
      & \signature\@thirdcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@fivecommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
      & \signature\@thirdcommittee\\
      & \signature\@fourthcommittee\\
    }
     & \signature{\@departmentchair}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}{
  xxxxx University\\
  \@copyrightyear}
\end{center}}

\def\startingpages{%
  \setcounter{page}{0}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \titlep
 % \signaturepage
  \immediate\openout12=\@bibliofile.aux
  \immediate\write12{\string\bibstyle{cubiblio}}
  \immediate\write12{\string\bibdata{\@reffile}}
  \@ifundefined{@abstract}{}{
    \doourabstract{\@abstract}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@dedication}{}{
    \doourdedication{\@dedication}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@acknowledgements}{}{
    \doouracknowledgements{\@acknowledgements}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@contributions}{}{
    \doourcontributions{\@contributions}
  }
  \contentspages
  \@ifundefined{@acronyms}{}{
    \doouracronyms{\@acronyms}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@symbols}{}{
    \dooursymbols{\@symbols}
  }
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{plain}
}

\def\doourabstract#1{%
  \sloppy
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{plain}
  }{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \pagestyle{plain}
  }
  \input{#1}
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{plain}
}

\def\doouracknowledgements#1{%
  \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
  \input{#1}
}

\def\doourdedication#1{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \include{#1}
}

\def\doourcontributions#1{%
  \chapter*{Contributions}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contributions}
  \input{#1}
}

\def\doouracronyms#1{%
  \chapter*{List of Acronyms}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
  \input{#1}
  \newpage
}

\def\dooursymbols#1{%
  \chapter*{List of Symbols}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
  \input{#1}
  \newpage
}

\def\contentspages{\newpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
      \@ifundefined{@myusetablespage}{}{
    {\addvspace{10pt}
    \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
    \def\addvspace##1{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \listoftables
    \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
  \newpage
  }
  \@ifundefined{@myusefigurespage}{}{
    {\addvspace{10pt}
    \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
    \def\addvspace##1{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures
    \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
  \newpage
  }
}

\def\newchapter#1{%
  \ifnum0=\value{mychaptercount}
    \@ifundefined{@noleadpages}{
      \startingpages
    }{}
    \setcounter{mychaptercount}{1}

  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\ele@chapapp\space \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}


\def\newappendix#1{%
  \ifnum0=\value{myappendixcount}
    \startappendix
    \setcounter{myappendixcount}{1}
  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

\def\startappendix{%
  \def\ele@chapapp{Appendix}
  \@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References}
     \bibliographystyle{cubiblio}
    \@ifundefined{@norefbib}{
      \bibliography{\@reffile}
    }{}
    \newpage
  }{}

  \appendix
  % This causes latex to number equations, tables, figures with
  % A-1, A-2, ...
%  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
%  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
%  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
}

% used for manuscript form chapter references
\def\refsforcb{%
  \@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
  }{
    \ifnum0=\value{mychapcitecount}
      \relax
    \else
      \newpage
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of References}
%      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References}
      \bibliography{\@reffile}
      \bibliographystyle{cubiblio}
      \newpage
    \fi
  }
}

\def\biblio{%
  \ifnum0=\value{myappendixcount}
    \startappendix
  \fi
  \ifnum0=\value{myfigcount}
    \relax
  \else
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myusefigurespage}\fi
  \fi
  \ifnum0=\value{mytablecount}
    \relax
  \else
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myusetablespage}\fi
  \fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
  \@input{\@bibliofile.bbl}
}

\def\bibliox{\bibliography{\@reffile}}

\@ifundefined{@norefbib}{
  \let\@enddocumenthook\biblio
}{
  \let\@enddocumenthook\bibliox
}
```

Comment: I think this question has been closed too hastily. The problem may be caused by the OP's document class, so the question may not be a duplicate. In any case the OP should be given time to provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `cuthesis.sty` is the version found [here](http://code.google.com/p/sim4j/source/browse/trunk/thesis/thesis/?r=381), you can do as follows.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cuthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but if I use this in main file, I cannot get "List of Figures" & "list of Tables" in my table of contents.

Comment: @asf --- `\listoffigures` works fine for me.

Comment: It should automatically be created by using this style file. But what I get is only number 1,2,3,....

Comment: @asf, can you confirm that Ian is using the right style file? That would be a good start. Then make sure you have compiled the .tex a couple of times.

Comment: I don't know. I get my file not from that website.

Comment: @asf --- Perhaps you could edit your question so that it includes a complete [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2417). Then it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Andy, it seems that your answer doesn't work for me. Although I can use \numberwithin{table}{chapter} to get what I want in the content. But I cannot get "list of figures" and "list of tables" in "table of contents", and these two lists won't show at the beginning of the whole content file.

Comment: Ian, can I create a minimal example then email to you for checking? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @asf --- I have suggested that your question be reopened (see above). If that happens you can edit the question and insert your example there. Otherwise, you could ask a new question (in which case this one will probably be deleted).

Answer (score 0):

I know in document class "report", "book" would make the figure index as figure 1.1, figure 1.2 ....

It's easier to renew the index style to exchange the index meaning:

```
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.\arabic{chapter}}     % numbering format: Figure
```

in the preamble area ( before `\begin{document}` ).
You could change the `\arabic{chapter}` to `\arabic{section}` or other static `1` values.

Same method could apply on Table and Equation.

```
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\arabic{table}-\arabic{chapter}}       % numbering format: Table
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}-\arabic{chapter}} % numbering format: Equation
```

So the MWE is that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\section{456}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Redefining `\thefigure` & friends is *not* sufficient; one must also reset the `figure` counter at the start of new sections. In your example, the first figure in a second section would be labelled "Figure 2.2".

Comment: @lockstep, You mention that second index would reset every section, but what cause it propagate?